# Unable to install mongodb in laravel

Tags: php, apache, mongodb, laravel-5

I am trying to setup mongodb for `Laravel Framework version 5.2.29`. My mongo php driver version is `ext-mongo 1.6.8    The mongo PHP extension`.

My Mongo version is 3.2

I have installed mongodb successfully, i can start mongod and mongo and create collections.

I have placed `php_mongo.dll` file in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext`
and copied `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\libsasl.dll` to C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin and added `extension=php_mongo.dll` in `php.ini` file in both php and apache.

I have checked my phpinfo, [image]

and now, I am trying to run `composer require jenssegers/mongodb` through command prompt from my project

The error I got is 
[image]

Donno what else I want to do to fix this error. Please help

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

CLI is normaly not using the same `php.ini` as apache is doing.

try `php -i` in your cmd which is phpinfo(). Now search for the Loaded Configuration File. Is the value of it the `php.ini` file you just edited?

Comment: Yes it is the same file

Answer (score 0):

it tells you, that you should enable mongodb extension in php.ini file. open php.ini file (path is shown on your photo) find `;extension=php_mongo.dll` and remove semicolon from it `;` . by default some extensions are disabled (commented). so you need to uncomment it, if you want to use it